# How to disable function View Edit Delete

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

how to map on my function (checkedCreate) the name: 'Attachments'. I have a checkbox if checked mapped the name: ' Attachments' then I will disable a function. Hoping some could help me and correct my codes. I really don't  know how to do it.

Here's the error I received:
[image: Error Message ELEMENT_DATA.name]

[image: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Masterfile[]'.]

My code look like this: but my code here has an error

```
checkedCreate(trigger:MatCheckboxChange){
this.tocreate = trigger.checked
If(ELEMENT_DATA.name = 'Attachements')
var a = this.attachment.openDialog(); 
a = this.roles.controls['isCreate'].disable();
}
```

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export interface Masterfile {
  name: string;
  position: number;

}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Masterfile[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Attachments'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Chart of Accounts'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Funds'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Item Category'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Item Sub Category'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Items'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Procurement Category'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Responsibility Center'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Stockroom'}, 
  {position: 10, name: 'Supplier'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Unit of Measurement'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modules-dialog',
  templateUrl: './modules-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modules-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ModulesDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name','actions','actions1','actions2','actions3'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  test:any;
  roles:FormGroup;

  tocreate: Boolean;
  
  
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.roles = this.formBuilder.group({  
      isCreate: [false, Boolean]  
    })

  }
 
  checkedCreate(trigger:MatCheckboxChange){
    this.tocreate = trigger.checked

  }
  

}
```

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="roles">
    
<mat-table class="sample" [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Masterfile Lists</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
                    
                
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Create </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" formControlName="isCreate" 
(change)="checkedCreate($event)"></mat-checkbox>
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: You say it has an error. Can you also include the error in the body of your question?

Comment: Include the error please.
btw ELEMENT_DATA.name is Attachments, not Attachement. When you have 1 control then you can just use a formcontrol instead of a group.